# NordNet API asks for public key (PEM key) and says it provides one, but it is nowhere to be found

Tags: python, api

Investment bank [NordNet's API docs](https://www.nordnet.fi/externalapi/docs/api) say a login string should be encrypted with a public key, but I am confused as to where I can get such key.

I have tried googling it, but I can not find an answer, could you help?

Thanks!

I tried to look for a public key online and see if I'm supposed to generate an RSA key myself. None of these approaches worked.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The Nordnet API is no longer open for everybody. Last time I asked them, it was only open for Swedish customers and that might not even be the case any longer.

Contact your local Nordnet office for API key